# Parent failed to evaluate: variable not available - sprite kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I am getting an error when I have a collision. All my collision are working fine except one, and the error here is the error. I don't understand what it means completely, and it is a runtime error, not a build time error.

`(SKNode) SpriteKit.SKNode = <parent failed to evaluate: variable not available>`

The code:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let body1 = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode
    let body2 = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode
}
```

What does the error mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You killed your node, but the system has not removed it yet

Comment: @KnightOfDragon So basically, my node has been deleted from my code, but the system didn't delete it yet? So how do I stop this error from occuring?

Comment: it is best to kill the node on the didEndUpdate method, and have a flag setup so that you can skip evaluations

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try it now.

Comment: Yeah, you want to treat each update like a frozen moment in time,  by killing in the middle of your update cycle,  you break the space time continuum because you have matter that both exists and doesn't exist

Comment: Must be the old 'duplicate calls to `didBegin()`' problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let bodyA = contact.bodyA
    let bodyB = contact.bodyB

    guard let nodeA = bodyA.node as? SKSpriteNode,
          let nodeB = bodyB.node as? SKSpriteNode
    else {return}

    guard let parentNodeA = nodeA.parent,
          let parentNodeB = nodeB.parent
    else {return}

    //all your stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I like your idea, but I think it might be easier to use didEnd contact like how KnightOfDragon suggested.